# PostgreSQL export large object to client

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a PostgreSQL 9.1 database in which pictures are stored as large objects.
Is there a way to export the files to the clients filesystem through an SQL query?

```
select lo_export(data,'c:\img\test.jpg') from images where id=0;
```

I am looking for a way similar to the line above, but with the client as target.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

this answer is very late but will be helpful so some one i am sure

To get the images from the **server** to the **client system** you can use this

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\psql.exe" -h 192.168.1.101 -p 5432 -d mDB -U mYadmin -c  "\lo_export 19135 'C://leeImage.jpeg' ";
```

Where

1. **h 192.168.1.101**   : is the server  system IP
2. **-d mDB**            : the database name
3. **-U mYadmin**        : user name
4. **\lo_export**        :  the export function that will create the image at the client system location
5. **C://leeImage.jpeg** : The location and the name of the target image from the OID of the image
6. **19135**             : this is the OID of the image in you table.

the documentation is here [commandprompt.com](http://www.commandprompt.com/ppbook/c12119)

Answer (score 2):

Georg,

According to the [documentation for 9.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/lo-interfaces.html#LO-EXPORT), lo_export is relative to the client executing the call. So if clientA is connected to databaseB, when clientA executes your SQL, lo_export should create the file on clientA where you've told it to.

---

In light of the fact that you've stated your using JDBC under MATLAB (I'm not familiar with what you can do under there nor am I familiar with the interface to perform the call), if you are calling this from a JDBC connection manually:

```
java.sql.Connection conn= ...
java.sql.Statement stmt= conn.createStmt();
java.sql.ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery("select data from images where id=0");
// Assume one result
rs.next();
// Gets the blob input stream
InputStream blobData= rs.getInputStream(1);

// At this point you will have to write it to a file. 
// See below

rs.close();
stmt.close();
conn.close();
```

I have played very loose and fast with the JDBC operations for brevity here. There should be more error checking as well as try/catch/finally statements to wrap and clean up the connections.

[File copy example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7749002/289625).

Comment: Thanks! I am very new to this and a bit confused. The lo_export you link to is a C function, but I would like to use a SQL query to do the same.
This works for server side lo_import and lo_export, but I don't understand how to accomplish this from server side. At the moment my workaround is to call psql with 
    -c \lo_export foo,'bar'
as additional argument.

Comment: Sadly not, I am new to Stackoverflow as well and submitted the reply before by pressing return, when all I wanted was a line break. :D

Comment: How are you connecting to the instance? Using psql?

Comment: AH HA! ok I see what you're trying to do

Comment: No I am using JDBC through MATLAB.

Comment: AH! Even better - Ok so are you writing code to do some processing of these results (presumably in Java)?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, because all the PostgreSQL server can do is send back data to the client through the network connection that the client has established.
In particular, it can't create a file on the client filesystem, only client code can do that.

Comment: its possible with this `\lo_export lo_oid filename

    The large object export command; this lets you export the large object with OID lo_oid to filename on your local filesystem. This is different from the lo_export() server function in the same way the \copy and the SQL COPY commands are different. `

from http://www.commandprompt.com/ppbook/c12119

Comment: The question says "trough an SQL query", and \lo_export is not a SQL query, nor can be part of an SQL query. It's an internal command of the psql client program.

Answer (score 1):

Source: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/lo-funcs.html

```
CREATE TABLE image (
    name            text,
    raster          oid
);

SELECT lo_creat(-1);       -- returns OID of new, empty large object

SELECT lo_create(43213);   -- attempts to create large object with OID 43213

SELECT lo_unlink(173454);  -- deletes large object with OID 173454

INSERT INTO image (name, raster)
    VALUES ('beautiful image', lo_import('/etc/motd'));

INSERT INTO image (name, raster)  -- same as above, but specify OID to use
    VALUES ('beautiful image', lo_import('/etc/motd', 68583));

SELECT lo_export(image.raster, '/tmp/motd') FROM image
    WHERE name = 'beautiful image';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is borderline relevant, but since this StackOverflow question comes up every time someone searches for "lo_export" and I had to trial and error it due to lack of documentation, every object stored in `raster` column of table `image` can be exported to `/tmp/exportdir/` with statement:

```
SELECT lo_export(image.raster, concat('/tmp/exportdir/', image.id))
FROM image
```

This assumes that the column named `id` identifies each row and contains a value that can be used as a file name.