# What happens when you copy something A to B initiated from C?

Tags: windows, networking, copy, server

So I'm on computer C. I have network drives mapped to 2 different computers as A and B. I start copy from A to B. What does C do? Does it copy file to its local, writes chunk to memory or something else? I'm interested in Windows Server's behaviour on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?

> If you are using Windows Explorer on desktop A to transfer files from
>   server B to server C, then yes the files are traveling from B to A to
>   C.
>
> The easiest way to bypass this method is to use a Remote Desktop
>   Connection to server B and then copy to Server C.
>
> There are other alternative methods, such as using telnet, ssh,
>   scripts, and 3rd party programs that allow you to bypass the
>   middleman.

Source: http://www.howtogeek.com/149277/is-my-local-computer-an-intermediary-when-i-transfer-files-between-remote-servers/

Comment: This is useful but need more detail. Like is there disk i/o involved or is it handled through network layer or something?

Comment: It's network / memory as I understand it. SO article for writing your own http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92114/how-can-i-copy-a-large-file-on-windows-without-copyfile-or-copyfileex