# Report progress copy for large file WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

i finally find the way to use the progress bar for showing me the progress into copy files, it's working fine for little files but when i'm trying to copy large file i can't see any progress only when the file finish to copy.

how can i receive report of the size already copied?

here's my code:

```
        private void btnCopy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string source = @"C:\mi";
        string dest = @"C:\test";
        // Copy from the current directory, include subdirectories.
        string destDirName = dest + "\\" + source.Substring(source.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);
        if (!Directory.Exists(dest))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
        }
        DirectoryCopy(source, destDirName, true);
    }

    private void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
    {
        double Size = 0;
        double totalsize = 0;
        double filepercent = 0;

        // Get the subdirectories for the specified directory.
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);

        if (!dir.Exists)
        {
            throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
                "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
                + sourceDirName);
        }

        DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
        // If the destination directory doesn't exist, create it.
        if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
        }

        // Get the files in the directory and copy them to the new location.
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
        int filecount = files.Count();
        int i = 1;
        foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
        {
            totalsize += fi.Length;
        }
        totalsize = Math.Round((totalsize / 1048576), 2);

        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            Size += Math.Round(((double)file.Length / 1048576), 2);
            filepercent = Size * 100 / totalsize;
            string temppath = System.IO.Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
            file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)filepercent,"Files " + i + "/" + filecount + " " + Size + "/" + totalsize + " Mb");
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            i++;
        }

        ////If copying subdirectories, copy them and their contents to new location.
        if (copySubDirs)
        {
            foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
            {
                string temppath = System.IO.Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
                DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
            }
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressbar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        lblpercent.Content = e.UserState as string;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("All the files were copied!");
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All things in

```
 file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
 backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)filepercent,"Files " + i + "/" + filecount + " " + Size + "/" + totalsize + " Mb");
        Thread.Sleep(100);
```

You copying whole file using system function and than report progress.

If you want to see progress of copying single file you have to copy it yourself like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/92165/1558147).

in your code it will looks like

```
int buflen = 1024;
byte[] buf = new byte[buflen];
long totalBytesRead = 0;
using (FileStream sourceStream = 
          new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open))
{
    using (FileStream destStream = 
                new FileStream(tempPath, FileMode.CreateNew))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            numReads++;
            int bytesRead = sourceStream.Read(buf, 0, buflen);
            if (bytesRead == 0) break; 
            destStream.Write(buf, 0, bytesRead);

            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

            // TODO: Here you can track your progress
            // backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)filepercent,"Files " + i + "/" + filecount + " " + Size + "/" + totalsize + " Mb");        

            if (bytesRead < buflen) break;

        }
    }
}
```